# Integer partition weighted minimum of maximum

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Given a non-negative integer `n` and a positive real weight vector `w` with dimension `m`, partition `n` into a length-`m` non-negative integer vector that sums to `n` (call it `v`) such that `max w_iv_i` is the smallest, that is, we want to find the vector `v` such that the maximum of element-wise product between `w` and `v` is the smallest. There maybe several partitions, and we only want the smallest value of `max w_iv_i` among all possible `v`.

Seems like this problem can use a greedy algorithm to solve. From a target vector `v` for `n-1`, we add 1 to each entry, and find the minimum among those `m` vectors. but I don't think it's correct. The intuition is that it might add "over" the minimum. That is, there exists another partition not yielded by the add 1 procedure that falls in between the "minimum" of `n-1` produced by this greedy algorithm and that of `n` produced by this greedy algorithm. Can anyone prove if this is correct or incorrect?

Comment: I think the greedy algorithm works. For example, `w = [2, 5, 7]`. The sequence of values when multiplying by 2 is 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14... For 5 it's 0,5,10,15... For 7 it's 0,7,14,... If you collate those sequences you have 0,2,4,5,6,7,8,10,10,12,14,14,15. For a given `n` you need to take the first `n+1` values from that collated sequence. The last value taken is the answer. The greedy algorithm is doing the same thing, but without first computing the entire collated sequence.

Comment: Thanks! I believe this is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the maximum element-wise product P, then you can just set v<sub>i</sub> = floor(P/w<sub>i</sub>) until you run out of n.

Use binary search to find the smallest possible value of P.

The largest guess you need to try is n * min(w), so that means testing log(n) + log(min(w)) candidates, spending O(m) time for each test, or O(m*(log n + log(min(w))) all together.